# Password Protecting Solr On Jetty

Tags: java, security, solr, jetty, solrj

So, I password protected solr using guide [here](http://muddyazian.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-require-password-authentication.html) .

It worked fine and I am no longer able to access admin console without providing password. I am using solrj for accessing solr. The problem is, even after password protecting admin console, I am able to access solr via solrj. Jetty provides security to admin console, and not the solr instance itself. How can I make my solr completely password protected ?

Answer (score 0):

You should apply password for every URL patterns at Solr:

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```